# Export CSVs with variable names using a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a code that is running that extracts a certain number of rows from a dataframe and writes them to a CSV with a variable file name "Stored_files_1,2,3,4,5... and so on.

```
for i in range(round(len(usersDf)/577)): #This ensures all rows are captured
```

`usersDf.loc[i*577:(i+1)*577,:].to_csv('Stored_files_'+str(i)+'.csv')`'

I would like to adapt my code above to name each csv using 2 lists that i have created using a columns from another DF

`period = file_list[0].tolist()`

`layer = file_list[2].tolist()`

The File names of the exported CSVs would look like this and the numbers to loop through would be in the lists
period 1, layer 1.csv
period 1, layer 2. csv
period 1, layer 3. csv and so on

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could iterate through the lists and generate a new filename to store the respective file.

```
for j in range(0, number_of_files):
    data = get_data_from_whatever_source(j)
    period_name = period[j]
    layer_name = layer[j]
    filename = f"{period_name}, {layer_name}.csv"
    save_your_custom_file_in_whichever_way_you_want(data, filename)
```